# make instances of 'MyModel' conform to 'Identifiable' protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I have MyModel defined to conform to the Identifiable protocol. However when I option click on myModel inside MyCell, the type is MyModel, not MyModel: Identifiable and the error message I get because of this is the following:

> Referencing initializer 'init(_:columns:columnsInLandscape:vSpacing:hSpacing:vPadding:hPadding:content:)' on 'QGrid' requires that 'MyModel' conform to 'Identifiable'

How would I make an instance of MyModel conform to the Identifiable protocol?

```
import SwiftUI
import QGrid

class MyModel: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID

    typealias ID = UUID
    let name: String

    init(id: UUID, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {

    let array = [MyModel(id: UUID(), name: "Name #1"), MyModel(id: UUID(), name: "Name #2")]

    var body: some View {
        QGrid(array, columns: 3) { //compiler error appears here
            value in
            MyCell(myModel: value)
        }
    }
}


struct MyCell: View {
    let myModel: MyModel //if I change this to MyModel & Identifiable I get the error "Protocol 'Identifiable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(myModel.name)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I imported QGrid version 0.1.3 via Swift Package Manager and copy-pasted your code into a blank project and could not reproduce the compiler error you're describing. Everything compiles successfully.

Comment: And did the code run? I still get the same error, I updated to the newest XCode 11.3.1 and QGrid 0.1.3.

Comment: I did not try running it because you only mentioned a compiler error, not a runtime one.

Comment: Just asked because sometimes Compiler errors don’t show up until trying to run the code

Comment: I just now tried running it, and yeah it runs fine.

Comment: Could you share Xcode version and swift version ?

Comment: Sure. Xcode version 11.3.1 (11C504), Swift 5.1.3 (but it shows up as "Swift 5" in Xcode).

Comment: I created a new project and pasted in the code and added the dependency as you did, and now everything is for some weird reason working fine. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Yeah I guess there must be some other conflict going on in your original project, or something.